# How to make a triangle that always faces at the same point?

Tags: javascript, rotation, geometry, processing, p5.js

[image]

In a p5/processing project i have been working on, i need to create a line that has a triangle in the middle which always faces one of the connection points of the line.
It is pretty easy to create one that stands still, but my endpoints move around and rotate.
I need to find a way to also rotate the little triangle when the line shifts to this "|" from this "---".
My current code goes like this:

```js
      let middleX = (fromX + toX)/2;
      let middleY = (fromY + toY)/2;
      triangle(middleX,middleY+5,middleX+5,middleY,middleX,middleY-5);
      line(fromX , fromY, toX, toY);
```

As you can anticipate, this doesn't work with rotations.
I need help :).
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: basically you need to rotate your triangle, here is formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)

Comment: More detail would be helpful. What do you mean by _connection points_? We presume _endpoints_ refers to the line (segment). An image with examples would be much better than **|** and **--**. Do you want the triangle with one vertex on the line or its base parallel to the line or something else? Is the triangle to be isosceles or equilateral or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @betakilo You are right! This was a bit ambigous. i am uploading some images now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. use [`atan2()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/atan2) to calculate the rotation between the two points,
2. use [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) to isolate the coordinate space (rotate locally without affecting the rest of the sketch (e.g. the line)
3. simply call `rotate()`: it takes in an angle in radians which is what `atan2()` returns

Here's an example based on your snippet:

```js
let fromX = 200;
let fromY = 200;
let toX = 300;
let toY = 100;
let triangleSize = 5;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  // test: change to position
  toX = mouseX;
  toY = mouseY;
  
  let middleX = (fromX + toX) / 2;
  let middleY = (fromY + toY) / 2;
  // calculate the angle between from -> to points
  let angle = atan2(toY - fromY, toX - fromX);
  // isolate coordinate system (indenting is purely visual, not required)
  push();
    // move to central position
    translate(middleX, middleY);
    // rotate from translated position
    rotate(angle);
    // render triangle
    triangle(0, triangleSize, triangleSize, 0, 0, -triangleSize);
  pop();
  
  line(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** that the order of transformations (translation, rotation, scale) is important.
(e.g. if rotate, then translate the triangle will land in a different location)

Also you draw the triangle as pointing to the right by default which aligns nicely with 0 radians rotation.

Comment: This worked flawlessly! I was trying an implementation like this earlier today but it was constantly failing. Now i know why, it was the order of transformations as you mentioned. Thanks again for a wonderful answer.

Comment: A pleasure :) As a next step you should encapsulate a few of those lines into a [`function`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/function) which takes from/to parameters so you can easily reuse it for the rest of the lines in your graph. Have fun !